# Equivalent power BJT transistor 2sa758 and 2sc898 for Sansui au 6600 Amplifier

Tags: power, transistors, amplifier

I am restoring my Sansui au6600, at the moment I am recapping it, however I will have to replace the two final power transistors for the left channel which I found out to be faulty.
The parts listed in the service manual for the two transistors are listed as 
2sa758 and 2sc898. Below is the datasheet of both
[image]

However I did find not those two but instead there were two motorola mj15022 and mj15025 (both faulty) which I suspect to be counterfit not genuine , but I could be wrong. below is datasheet of the latter
[image]
[image]

As I am finding it difficoult here in Europe to find the two genuine 2sa758 and 2sc898 a local technician has got for sale two transistors that he does say that are equivalent and will work fine. The transistors are 
2sa745a and 2sc1402. Could you please help me to understand wheather these two transistors are ok and if not how in real life will effect the proper functioning of the Sansui au660
Below is the datasheet of  the 2sa745a and 2sc1402
[image]

Thank you very much , your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What really matters is the I_V output curve, which shows the flatness of the Iout versus Vout for a constant Ibase; these tilted curves are called the Early effect. A high Early voltage (seldom spec'd in transistors) determines the power supply rejection at high frequencies (where the negative feedback has weak ability to control the loudspeaker voltage).

I'd install a small cooling fan in your (upgraded) amplifier; keep those hot transistors 20 degrees cooler and their lifespan should exceed yours and that of the next owner.